# How to select specific rows of all columns based on the specific values in r?

Tags: r

```
C1 C2 C3 C4
 2  3  4  5
 3  3  3  3 
 4  5  6  6
 4  4 6   3
 3  3  3  3
34 4   4 45  
3   3  3  3
```

I wanted to select the enitre row which has only contain "3 values" . I have used a x <- dataset(dataset, column[,C1:C4]==3)

But It doesnt work properly in my entire dataset. Is there any better code than this?
Thanks

Comment: Assuming your data frame is called `dataset`, try `dataset[2, ]`.

Comment: Here's a handy tutorial: https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/free-introduction-to-r/chapter-5-data-frames?ex=6

Comment: Seems like you might want `dataset[rowSums(dataset == 3) == ncol(dataset), ]`

Comment: Or maybe `merge(list(C1=3,C2=3,C3=3,C4=3),dat)` if you are going to be searching for specific combinations?

Comment: `A[unique(which(A==3,arr.ind = T)[,1]),]` if A were your matrix, maybe?

Comment: With [the forthcoming version of dplyr](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr) this could be done as `df %>% filter_all(all_vars(. == 3))`. I'm not sure I like the syntax, but this is the sort of use-case it's there for.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a more elegant way, but this will do the job:

```
dataset = matrix(1:16, ncol = 4)
dataset[2,] = rep(3, 4)
dataset[apply(dataset, 1, function(row) all(row == 3)),]
```

Comment: edited to reflect updated question

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick one-liner rusty approach but works for more than one row and can be tuned to have a parameter (or more than one parameter) inside a function.
Here's an example:

```
A
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
[1,] 3.000000 3.000000 3.000000 3.000000 3.000000
[2,] 9.471191 9.471191 9.471191 9.471191 9.471191
[3,] 3.000000 3.000000 3.000000 3.000000 3.000000
[4,] 6.469733 6.469733 6.469733 6.469733 6.469733
[5,] 8.040697 8.040697 8.040697 8.040697 8.040697

A[unique(which(A==3,arr.ind = T)[,1]),]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    3    3    3    3    3
[2,]    3    3    3    3    3
```

There are some issues, for example, you lost the row indices by doing that. I hope it's what you're looking for.